# Custom np++ functionlist expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

Oh, I'm having trouble just understanding what I'm doing here.

I'm creating a custom Notepad++ FunctionList.  I know how to add it, and it's parsing, but I can't [figure out from the docs](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/function-list/) how to specify the regex correctly.

In my code file (for a program called Squiffy), it has sections, kind of like an .ini file, so I started by copying the ini file's functionlist code.

I'm looking for sections like this:  `[[something]]:`  on it's own line, and for subsections like this: `[somesubsection]:`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<NotepadPlus>
    <functionList>
        <!-- File format used for: .sq         -->
        <parser displayName="Squiffy" id="Squiffy" 
            commentExpr=""
        >
            <function mainExpr=mainExpr="^\[\[.*\]\]\:$" >
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="^\[\[.*\]\]*"/>
                </functionName>
            </function>
        </parser>
    </functionList>
</NotepadPlus>
```

My problem is that I don't really understand what `mainExpr` and `nameExpr` are supposed to find.  I know I can find the sections with the regex I have in `mainExpr`, but I'm not sure what to with the `nameXpr` field.

Comment: I think for nameExpr it states `here you define the regular expression to find the function name.` Perhaps try it like this `\[[^][]*]:`

Comment: What does *that* mean "find the function name"?  Does it mean find it in the `mainExpr`?  What I have in the `mainExpr` is already the function name.  What is the difference?   (I tried what you put, but it doesn't show anything in the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmph.  Nobody had anything to say!  So [I posted on the notepad++ forum](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20390/how-to-understand-the-functionlist-parameters), which is where this solution comes from:

```
        <parser
            id="Squiffy" displayName="Squiffy" commentExpr=""
        >
            <function
                mainExpr="(?-s)^\[(?:\[([^\[\]\r\n]+)\]|(?1))\]:"
            >
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="[^\[\]\r\n]+" />
                </functionName>
            </function>
        </parser>
```

And [here is a thread describing](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19480/faq-desk-function-list-basics) just notepad++ functionlists are configured.